# Adding attribute (capacity) to node and edge in a graph created using dictionary

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary, networking, graph, networkx

I have created 2 small graphs using python dictionaries and Networkx.

Now I want to assign and display an attribute (capacity) to the nodes and the edges. I failed in doing this when a graph was created using the dictionary. My code is:

```
#VNFGraph
Nf = {'VNF1', 'VNF2', 'VNF3', 'VNF4', 'VNF5'}
Lf = {('VNF1', 'VNF2'),('VNF2', 'VNF3'),('VNF3', 'VNF4'), ('VNF2', 'VNF5'),('VNF5', 'VNF3')}

# SERVERGraph
Ns = {'S1', 'S2', 'S3', 'S4', 'S5'}
Ls = {('S1', 'S2'),('S1', 'S4'),('S2', 'S4'),('S2', 'S3'),('S4', 'S3'),('S4', 'S5'),('S3', 'S5')}

graph1 = nx.DiGraph()
graph1.add_nodes_from(list(Nf))
graph1.add_edges_from(list(Lf))

graph2 = nx.Graph()
graph2.add_nodes_from(list(Ns))
graph2.add_edges_from(list(Ls))
graph2.add_edge("S1", "S2", weight=4.7)

pos1 = ({'VNF1': (0, 6), 'VNF2': (2, 6), 'VNF3': (4, 6), 'VNF4': (6, 6), 'VNF5': (3, 4)})

pos = ({'S1': (0, 1), 'S2': (2, 2), 'S3': (4, 2), 'S4': (3, 1), 'S5': (6, 1)})

fig1, ax1 = plt.subplots(figsize=(7, 7))
nx.draw_networkx_nodes(graph1, pos=pos1, ax=ax1, edgecolors='black', node_size=1100)

nx.draw_networkx_labels(graph1, pos=pos1, ax=ax1, labels=dict(zip(Nf, Nf)), font_size=7)

nx.draw_networkx_edges(graph1, pos=pos1, ax=ax1, node_size=900, arrowsize=25)

nx.draw_networkx_nodes(graph2, pos=pos, ax=ax1, edgecolors='black', node_size=800)

nx.draw_networkx_labels(graph2, pos=pos, ax=ax1, labels=dict(zip(Ns, Ns)), font_size=8)

nx.draw_networkx_edges(graph2, pos=pos, ax=ax1, node_size=900, arrowsize=25)

plt.axis('on')
plt.show()
```

I want to assign values (capacity attribute) to each node and link and display that too.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the capacity to the nx.draw_commands as a list of values (which are in the same order as the nodes/edges of your graph). My usual approach is to write the attributes to the graph and then read them out and pass them to the draw commands:

```
import networkx as nx 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from random import randint

Nf = {'VNF1', 'VNF2', 'VNF3', 'VNF4', 'VNF5'}
Lf = {('VNF1', 'VNF2'),('VNF2', 'VNF3'),('VNF3', 'VNF4'), ('VNF2', 'VNF5'),('VNF5', 'VNF3')}

graph1 = nx.DiGraph()
graph1.add_nodes_from(list(Nf))
graph1.add_edges_from(list(Lf))

pos1 = ({'VNF1': (0, 6), 'VNF2': (2, 6), 'VNF3': (4, 6), 'VNF4': (6, 6), 'VNF5': (3, 4)})

'''
Create a dict of node and edge weights:
Dict has to have following form: {node_label: {attribute1: value1, attribute2: value2 ...}}
'''

node_weight = {n:{'weight':randint(100, 1000)} for n in graph1.nodes()}
edge_weight = {e:{'weight':randint(1, 5)} for e in graph1.edges()}

'''
Write attributes to graph
'''
nx.set_node_attributes(graph1, node_weight)
nx.set_edge_attributes(graph1, edge_weight)

'''
Get attributes from graph; returns dict: {node_label: value (of specified attribtue)}
In order to pass them to nx.draw you need a list, so unpack the values of the dict
This way you avoid messing up the order of the nodes
'''
node_size = list(nx.get_node_attributes(graph1, 'weight').values())
edge_size = list(nx.get_edge_attributes(graph1, 'weight').values())


fig1, ax1 = plt.subplots(figsize=(7, 7))

nx.draw_networkx_nodes(graph1, pos=pos1, ax=ax1, edgecolors='black', node_size=node_size)
nx.draw_networkx_labels(graph1, pos=pos1, ax=ax1, labels=dict(zip(Nf, Nf)), font_size=7)
nx.draw_networkx_edges(graph1, pos=pos1, ax=ax1, width = edge_size, arrowsize=25)

plt.axis('on')
plt.show()
```